# F# check if generic type parameter is discriminated union

Tags: generics, f#, discriminated-union

How to specify the type of discriminated union when creating a constraint? What should I write instead of `DiscriminatedUnion`?

```
let f<'U when 'U :> DiscriminatedUnion> ()
```

Comment: So `'U` could be *any* discriminated union, but not a record type? I don't think this is possible. Here's a [list of constraints supported by F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints). Moreover, I don't understand what this constraint would accomplish. In other words, how would `f` make use of the fact that `'U` is a discriminated union **at compile-time**?

Comment: DU internally is just a class, see [decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AbEAzAzmgExAGoAfCABxgDsACAZQE9cAXGAWwFgAoHlxqrQCyjAEoxIUArQC8tAN60AktJC0AltRYBuWgDkAhuxi01rKJoDmtAL48+AkyIAiAVVk9aX2qVriCnt6+AOKwNLQQ2LTmVkA==). There's no any base class for DU nor for records. You can make constraint over 5 interfaces, but DU and records will both match it

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any way to enforce this check at compile time. At runtime you could use `FSharpType.IsUnion` [ref](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-reflection-fsharptype.html#IsUnion) in your implementation and handle the false case possibly by throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at compile-time for DUs that are compiled as enums:

```ml
let foo<'t when 't : enum<int>> (t : 't) =
  string t

type Fruit =
  | Apple = 0
  | Banana = 1
  | Cherry = 2

foo Fruit.Apple |> printfn "%s"

// Compile-time error
foo "abc" |> printfn "%s"
```

However, DUs compiled as classes will not satisfy this constraint:

```ml
type Shape =
  | Square of int
  | Rectangle of int * int

// Compile-time error
foo (Square 2) |> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: This is just confusing. An enum is not a DU. Enums do not have the same features as DUs.